# How to redirect a sub category change (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

A sub directory has changed on my site and I need to redirect traffic from

```
http://url.com/old-sub/lots-of-content.php
```

to

```
 http://url.com/new-sub/lots-of-content.php
```

What is the code required to do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mod_rewrite is available:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-sub/(.*)$ /new-sub/$1
```

Comment: Cheers Floern.

If I already have mod rewrite rules for SEF URLs, is your suggestion placed at the very end of the .htaccess file?

Comment: If you have `/old-sub/..` in your SEF URL you should place it at the beginning, if not you can place it at the end.